# Rxjs concat Observable with condition

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to execute a rest call based on a condition. The call will be executed but, depending on the condition, it will be executed after another rest call.
For now, I tried in this way but I'm sure it's not the best way to do it:

```js
    if(!checkTokenValidation()) {
       this.service.getToken().pipe(
          map(response => {
             setToken(response);
          })
       ).subscribe(() => {
          this.service.search().subscribe(data => {
             ...
          })
       })
    } else {
       this.service.search().subscribe(data => {
             ...
          })  
    }
```

I need to do search in every case but, if token is not valid, I need to get new token first.
Is there a way to do this without redundant code?
Thanks

Comment: it will be better if you use HTTPinterceptor to check, validate, and setToken in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be the following:

```js
    import { EMPTY, of } from "rxjs";
    import { map, tap, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
    
    // if token is valid, create an empty observable, else set the observable to the service.getToken api call
    var obs$ = checkTokenValidation() ? of(EMPTY) : this.service.getToken().pipe(map(response => setToken(response));
    // take the first observable and then map it to a new observable, a.k.a. the response from the service.search api call
    obs$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.service.search())
        .subscribe(data => {
             ...
      });
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're doing relies on some state you're not managing explicitly. That's fine, but it's always going to look slightly awkward in a declarative library like RxJS. You need the token, but then I immediately `ignoreElements`.

That might read strangely to you, but something like this should work:

```ts
( checkTokenValidation() ?
  EMPTY :
  this.service.getToken()
).pipe(
  tap(response => setToken(response)),
  ignoreElements(),
  concatWith(this.service.search())
).subscribe(data => {
  // ...
});
```